# Validación de float en Laravel

Tags: laravel, validación, vistas

Tengo una funcion que guarda notas:

```
public function guardarNotas(Request $request)
{   
    $this->validate($request, [
        'nota' => 'numeric|min:0|max:7|nullable', 

    ]);

    $notas = $request->input();

    foreach ($notas as $nota){
        $nota = Nota::updateOrCreate([
            'id_matricula' => $nota['idMatricula'],
            'id_evaluacion' => $nota['idEvaluacion']
            ], ['nota' => $nota['nota']]);
    }
    //responder true or false ? segun se guarda o devolver error
    return response()->json(array('success' => true));

}
```

Como puedo validar que las notas ingresadas sean de 1.0 a 7.0 ??

Ya intente con $this->validate. Tambien cree un Request y tampoco me funciona,
en el input tambien le coloque un pattern y nada

```
<input class="nota" size="1" style="text-align:center" pattern="([1-6](\.[0-9]{1,2})?)|7(\.00?)?" type="text" data-id-matricula="{{ $m->id }}" data-id-evaluacion="{{ $evaluaciones[$i]->id }}" value="{{ (isset($notas[$m->id]))? (isset($notas[$m->id][$evaluaciones[$i]->id]))?$notas[$m->id][$evaluaciones  [$i]->id]: 1.0 : 1.0 }}"/>
```

Al momento de guardar la nota, pasan igual los 7.1 en adelante también los 8 y 9.

codigo vista:

```html
@if (Auth::guard('profesor')->check()) 

@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('title','Listado de Alumnos')  

@section('content')


          
  <strong>Asignatura :   </strong>   <a>  {{$asignatura->nombre}}</a><br>
  @if(($asignatura->id_curso)== null)
  <strong>Curso  :  </strong><br>
  @else
  <strong>Curso : </strong> <a>{{$asignatura->curso->nombre." / ".$asignatura->curso->tipo}}</a><br>
  @endif
  <strong>Periodo :   </strong> <a>{{$asignatura->periodo." - ".$asignatura->created_at->year}}</a><br>
  @if(($asignatura->horario) == null )
  <strong>Horario :   </strong> <a>Sin Horario</a><br><br>
  @else
  <strong>Horario :    </strong> <a>{{$asignatura->horario}}</a><br><br>
  @endif
 
 <form name="notas">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
 
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
   
   <th width="120">Alumno</th>

   @foreach ($evaluaciones as $e)
    <th width="120">{{$e->nombre}}</th>
   @endforeach
   
   
          
  </tr>

   @foreach ($matriculados as $m)
    <tr>
     <td>{{$m->apellido_paterno." ".$m->apellido_materno." ".$m->nombre}}</td>
     @for($i=0, $length = count($evaluaciones); $i < $length; $i++)
           <td>
            <input class="nota" size="1" style="text-align:center" pattern="([1-6](\.[0-9]{1,2})?)|7(\.00?)?" type="text" data-id-matricula="{{ $m->id }}" data-id-evaluacion="{{ $evaluaciones[$i]->id }}" value="{{ (isset($notas[$m->id]))? (isset($notas[$m->id][$evaluaciones[$i]->id]))?$notas[$m->id][$evaluaciones [$i]->id]: 1.0 : 1.0 }}"/>
           </td>
           @endfor 
    </tr>
   @endforeach

 </table>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="guardarNotas()">Guardar</button>

 </form>

<script>
 function guardarNotas(){
  var object = [];

  $(".nota").each(function (index, element){
   object.push({
    'idMatricula': $(element).data('idMatricula'),
    'idEvaluacion': $(element).data('idEvaluacion'),
    'nota': $(element).val()
   });
  });

  $.ajax('../savecalificacionesasignatura', {
   contentType: 'aplication/json',
   data: JSON.stringify(object),
   method: 'post',
   headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('[name="_token"]').val()
   },
   success: function (data) {
    console.log('se ha guardado');
    window.location.replace("../datos-profesor/vercalificacion/" + {{ $asignatura->id }} );
   },
   error: function (data) {
    console.log('Error:', data)
   }
  });

 }
</script>

@endsection

@else

@include('layouts.error')

@endif
```

fotos de la vista [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y por que no lo validas Javascript ?

Comment: La 5.4, si en el resto del sistema me funcionan perfecto las validaciones con un request, solo en esta parte no me funcionan, quizas es por la funcion ajax o ni idea, y el size es para achicar el cuadrado xd

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar los datos que recibes en el request o en el controlador?

Comment: Estaba revisando y nisiquiera puedo hacer un dd() en el controlador, como que simplemente pasa a la siguiente vista. Debe ser por la success: function (data) {
    console.log('se ha guardado');
    window.location.replace("../datos-profesor/vercalificacion/" + {{ $asignatura->id }} );
   }, Como puedo solucionar eso?

Comment: la tabla notas solo tiene un campo para la nota, el id del matriculado y el id de la eveluacion a la que pertenece

Comment: Me expliqué mal, sin embargo con la imagen que agregaste ya respondiste lo que quería saber. ¿En cuál de los 12 campos del formulario (basado en la imagen) estás insertando una nota fuera del rango permitido? Ya sé que es lo que pasa, solo quiero confirmarlo.

Comment: Intente con todos los campos un numero 8, y todas pasan

Answer (score 0):

Agrega `use Validator;` como dependecia, en el controlador en donde esté tu funcion. Luego utiliza el siguiente código:

```
$notas = $request->input();      
$reglas =  array(
          'nota' => 'numeric|min:0|max:7|nullable', 
      );

  $validator = Validator::make($notas, $reglas)
  if (!$validator->fails()){
      //return response()->json(array('success' => true)); o la acción que desees realizar si los datos son válidos

  }

  return response()->json(array('success' => false));
```

**Verificar ajax**

> Verifica la validación de la respuesta en ajax de ésta forma, ya que estás redirigiendo sin importar si retorna true o false

```
            $.ajax('../savecalificacionesasignatura', {
                contentType: 'aplication/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(object),
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('[name="_token"]').val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    //Debes validar ya que retornará array("success",true) o array("success",false)
                    if(data.success === true)
                    {
                       console.log('se ha guardado');
                       window.location.replace("../datos-profesor/vercalificacion/" + {{ $asignatura->id }} );
                    }
                    else{
                      //el controlador retorna array("success"=>false)
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('Error:', data)
                }
            });
```

Comment: Gracias, pero no me funciono, lo coloque tal cual indicaste y al colocar un 9, pasa igual :(

Comment: @EdgardoEscobar en ese caso, debe ser la regla en si, prueba utilizar, "|between:0,7"

Comment: Claro min, max si que debería funcionar, y según lo que entiendo es que si la nota es 7.1 no guarde la nota, y que retorne false, ¿o me equivoco?. Mira la edición que hice, debía ser **(!$validator->fails())**.

Comment: Amigo estaba viedo y el problema no es la validacion, es que pasa de una vista a la otra, intente hacer un dd en el controlador guardarNota, y no me lo muestra, simplemente pasa a la siguiente vista :S

Comment: @EdgardoEscobar, he demorado un poco en replicar tu código, pero al fin y con lo descrito en la edición me ha funcionado, espero te funcione.

Comment: Tampoco me funciona, ahora coloco una nota y no pasa a la otra vista independiente que sea nota valida o invalida :(

Comment: @EdgardoEscobar muestra un **console.log(data)** dentro de success, sólo para cerciorarte de la información que retorna desde laravel, con una nota  válida y otra no válida